# Why cannot I get PsiClass from Kotlin but successful in Java

Tags: intellij-plugin, intellij-15

I try to get PsiClass from Kotlin file (the PsiFile instance is KtFile), but aways get null, In Java case is successful.

```java
    PsiFile psiFile = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.PSI_FILE);
    Editor editor = e.getData(CommonDataKeys.EDITOR);

    // null in kotlin
    PsiClass psiClass = getPsiClass(editor, psiFile);

    .....    

    private PsiClass getPsiClass(Editor editor, PsiFile file) {

        int offset = editor.getCaretModel().getOffset();
        PsiElement element = file.findElementAt(offset);

        if (element == null)
            element = file.findElementAt(offset - 1);
        if (element == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            PsiClass target = (PsiClass) PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(element, PsiClass.class);
            if (target == null) {
                element = file.findElementAt(offset - 1);
                if (element == null)
                    return null;
                target = (PsiClass) PsiTreeUtil.getParentOfType(element, PsiClass.class);
            }
            return target instanceof SyntheticElement ? null : target;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PsiClass` is used only for [java classes](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/java/java-psi-api/src/com/intellij/psi/PsiClass.java#L20). For Kotlin you should use [KtClass](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/psi/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/psi/KtClass.kt).